# How do you ignore generic type information and enable covariance of properties?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

i.e.

```
struct Child<Type> {
    var item: Type
}


class Parent {
    var children = [Child<**ANY subclass of UIView, for example**>]()
}
```

so if I have

```
let one = Child(item: UIView())
let two = Child(item: UITableView())
```

I'd like to have

```
let parent = Parent()
parent.children += [one,two]
```

If you type the `Parent` class's `children` property with `[Child<UIView>]` it will ONLY accept `Child` of the type `UIView` and not covariant types (i.e. `UITableView`.)

I need to handle a generic type that can have any subclass of UIView, but the `Parent` class doesn't even care about this property, it only touches other non-generic properties of the `Child` class.

Is there anyway of doing this that doesn't require Objective-C era dynamic type casting?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var children = [Child<**ANY subclass of UIView, for example**>]
> ```

Wouldn't that be nice? But forget it. Generics that you create are *not* covariant on the parameterized type, and nothing you can do will make them so. Where generics are, polymorphism is not.

You might object: But look at Optional! Look at Array! Yes, look at them. They get some sort of special dispensation from Apple. Even generics imported from Objective-C may now be covariant. But not *your* generics.

However, you might be able to make an array of differently parameterized Child objects by using *type erasure*. This would have nothing to do with the inheritance of the parameterized types, however. It would just be a way of allowing multiple Child structs to go into one array.